# Should I care about DPI and PPI when preparing images?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there something I should care about than making sure my images have 70 DPI? I always use point sizes for non-retina devices and double point sizes for retina devices when preparing my images. Now I always thought PPI is something that I don't care about - it just shows how dense are pixels on the concrete device. Meanwhile, I came upon some brownfield application project and saw something like that:

```
if ([deviceName isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"] ||
       [deviceName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"] ||
       [deviceName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"] ||
       [deviceName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"] ||
       [deviceName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"])

        _displayQuality = @"132";

    else if([deviceName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"] ||
            [deviceName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"] ||
            [deviceName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"])

        _displayQuality = @"163";

    else if([deviceName isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"] ||
            [deviceName isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"] ||
            [deviceName isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"] ||
            [deviceName isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"] ||
            [deviceName isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"] ||
            [deviceName isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"] ||
            [deviceName isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"] ||
            [machineName isEqualToString:@"iPad4,2"])

        _displayQuality = @"264";

    else

        _displayQuality = @"326";

   ....
```

Any ideas what the heck is that?

Comment: What is `_displayQuality` used for?

Answer (score 2):

No, just prepare you images with retina (@2x.png) and non retina resolutions.
Note: iPhone 6 to introduces @3x.png images

(Edited to swith @3x information from "rumor" to fact)

Comment: Seems right for @3x. This is what I could see after downloading the official resource.